# Edit onClipEvent Actionscript

Tags: events, actionscript-2

I am a beginner so please take it easy. First some history, I am trying to modify a flash movie (not created by me) that has 4 images in it.

I have to now add 2 more images (pic5.png and pic6.jpg) to the "slideshow" as shown in the attachment, I have added the 2 images to the library. The problem I am having (as I understand, I may be incorrect) is that `_root.count = 4` causes the movie to jump back to the first image after it displays the 4th one which does not display the 5th & 6th image.

My question, how do I edit the value of _root.count to 6, so that it will show all the 6 images. Additionally how do I create a hyperlink on each image.

Please can someone guide me.

Many thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your screen shot, Layer 2 (which contains the slideshow movieclip) is locked. If you unlock the layer by clicking on the padlock icon you should then be able to edit the script.

To edit the script double-click on the script in the Movie Explorer panel and the Actions panel should open. You can edit the script here.

The second part of your question - how to create a hyperlink - is very broad and there are many different ways to approach it. The most elegant approach would depend on how your project was structured.

The simplest way might be to define a variable to hold the path to the current image and add another onClipEvent handler.

So in the existing `onLoad` you would add…

```
this.path_to_image = http://your-domain.com/images/your-first-big-image.jpg;
```

Then add the new event handler

```
onClipEvent(mouseUp){
    getURL (this.path_to_image);
}
```

You would then have to update the `path_to_image` variable whenever the image changed.

```
slideshow.path_to_image = http://your-domain.com/images/your-next-big-image.jpg;
```